# Qt Dialog closed when application is in hidden state

Tags: visual-studio-2008, qt4

I have a question , I have a QDialog application which is in hidden state. And I have an Icon for that application. In that Icon's contextmenu, I have an option called "exit". When i click exit, a new message box appears for confirmation with "yes" and "No" button. If I go for "yes" , the application exits. But if i go for "No",it should not get exit but here it exits. It happens only when my application is in hidden state. But my case working fine when my application visible. what might be the cause ?Anyone have any idea ?

Comment: Could you provide some sample code?

Answer (score 0):

You have the [`quitOnLastWindowClosed`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qapplication.html#quitOnLastWindowClosed-prop) property set to true on your `QApplication` variable.  When the dialog goes away, that was the last visible window, so your application closes for you automatically.  If you want to prevent this behavior, you can set the variable otherwise, but you need to make sure to explicitly quit the event loop of the application variable in that case.